# Gridview scrolling stuck when try to scroll

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a grid view and I am trying to lasd a huge amount of data in it, 
if i try to reuse the layoutinflater in Gridview than the items are repeating and if i try to load new layout then scrolling stuck wht should I do in this case. Below is my code which I am using:

```
if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
    if (DownloadModualActivity.count_screen_normal == 1) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.magazine_container_mobile, parent,
                false);
        // v = li.inflate(R.layout.magazine_container_mobile, null);

    }
    if (DownloadModualActivity.count_screen_normal != 1) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // v = li.inflate(R.layout.magazine_container4, null);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.magazine_container4, parent, false);
    }

} else {
    v = (View) convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in [this](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) site, performance tips and patterns for listviews. You can apply the same to your gridview.

Check the async load, if you have heavy operations you should load in an asynctask to release the ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you are trying to attach two different views to your list view. Then what you need is those methods. Implement those methods and try again.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //  you need to return the index of your view you want to return according to your
    //  algorithm.
    return 0;
}


@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

And in the getView() method you can use this one below.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    YourDataModel item = getItem(position);

    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
    case 0:
        return getViewFirstItem(position, convertView, item);
    case 1:
        return getViewSecondItem(position, convertView, item);
    }

    return null;
}
```

And inside the getViewFirstItem() and getViewSecondItem() try to implement two different getView versions for two different View type.